# Dependency errors for gcc-4.8 while installing any package or software in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

I am getting the below error whenever I am trying to install any software.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.8 : Depends: cpp-4.8 (= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: binutils (>= 2.25.90.20160101) but 2.15.92.0.2-14 is to be installed
           Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libcloog-isl4 (>= 0.17) but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-5 : Depends: binutils (>= 2.26.1) but 2.15.92.0.2-14 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Breaks: binutils (< 2.20.1-1) but 2.15.92.0.2-14 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Hey  thanks for the reply. I tried as you mentioned but still same error. :(

Comment: Hey Kulfy. I am using 16.04 but I couldn't find any tag related to 16.04. So mentioned the available one 14.04.

Comment: I figured this out.

Comment: I disagree with the reviewers who reviewed this question as off topic because the error is not reproducible. The error message in this question is reproducible, and it could occur in similar situations where there was an unmet dependency related to a version conflict of a critical package like binutils.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue by re-installing the package `binutils`.
Now it is working fine.